# Adding Own Object Type to Array with array.append method

Tags: java, arrays

```
private State USA = new State("United States of America");
private State CAN = new State("Canada");
private State MEX = new State("Mexico");
private State[] stateArray;
public static void main()
{
}


public void addState(State state) //I need a way to add the Private objects called State into an array here. The command must take User Interface
{
    stateArray = stateArray.add(state);
}
```

Well, to sum it up, all I need is some kind of method(s) that can add items to an array as seen in the addState array

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it in a separate thread.  Don't edit your existing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use array:

```
private State USA = new State("United States of America");
    private State CAN = new State("Canada");
    private State MEX = new State("Mexico");
    private State[] stateArray = new State[3];
    int index = 0;
    public static void main()
    {
    }


    public void addState(State state) //I need a way to add the Private objects called State into an array here. The command must take User Interface
    {
       if(index < stateArray.length)
           stateArray[index++] = state;
    }
```

Or you can use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead array.

```
private State USA = new State("United States of America");
    private State CAN = new State("Canada");
    private State MEX = new State("Mexico");
    private ArrayList<State> stateArray = new ArrayList<State>;
    public static void main()
    {
    }


    public void addState(State state) //I need a way to add the Private objects called State into an array here. The command must take User Interface
    {
        stateArray.add(state);
    }
```

Comment: I've never used ArrayLists, will this allow me to traverse list with a loop?

Comment: Yes, you can...:)..Basically the difference between array and `ArrayList` is an array has fixed size, but the size in `ArrayList` can growth dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Using `List<State> sates = new ArrayList<State>();`

```
public void addState(State state){
  sates.add(state);
}
```